# Android spinner changing width causing drop down item to not display

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, width, spinner

I have a spinner which contains a list of weeks (1->52) plus an additional 'All Weeks' option. When ever I select a week number, such as '1', the spinner width decreases to the size needed to display '1'. This causes problems when trying to select 'All Weeks' again as the spinner drop down width is too small for the 'All Weeks' option to display, causing it to be a blank entry at the top. You can still select the blank entry however, and doing so causes the spinner to act as I would expect it (where the width is at least wide enough for the 'All Weeks' text).

Is there a way around this? I have come across `android:dropDownWidth` attribute, which setting it to `100dp` makes this problem go away. If I set it to `wrap_content`, it displays the same behaviour when there is no attribute, and this is what I would like ideally. I have tested on API 23 (6.0) and 22 (5.1), both have the same problem.

I have set up a basic new activity which has this problem, and the relevant spinner code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.week_spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

Style xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp" >

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try Better Spinner library for an android. In this library you don't have to use that All Weeks tag. It also has cool animations.

[BetterSpinner](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner)